# Trying to install application in WINE

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm trying to install the launcher for EmpireInFlames, which is a modded server of SWG. You can find the install at https://www.empireinflames.com/. When I download and run the installer, it seems to be fine, until the part where the window would appear.

I get the following error output.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000030 in 32-bit code (0x01d995ff).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:006b GS:0063
 EIP:01d995ff ESP:0032c290 EBP:0032c294 EFLAGS:00010246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:07c94000 EBX:07ca4000 ECX:0000000c EDX:000000c0
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0000000c
Stack dump:
0x0032c290:  00000000 0032c330 020eb009 00000000
0x0032c2a0:  07ca4000 0032c3d4 00000000 05c41700
0x0032c2b0:  05c41700 05c41700 05c41700 05c41620
0x0032c2c0:  05c41700 00000001 fffffc40 ffffffc0
0x0032c2d0:  fffffc40 000000c0 00000000 00000000
0x0032c2e0:  00000300 0032c3a8 00000000 00000040
Backtrace:
=>0 0x01d995ff EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c294)
  1 0x020eb009 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c330)
  2 0x020e3cb7 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c374)
  3 0x020eac2f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c3e8)
  4 0x021b4642 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c408)
  5 0x021b56a3 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032c43c)
  6 0x021b6c6b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d280)
  7 0x021b68a6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d3f0)
  8 0x021b6675 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d464)
  9 0x02143bac EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d4d0)
  10 0x02143355 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d500)
  11 0x0213a919 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d518)
  12 0x0213aac5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d558)
  13 0x02143e0b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d5c4)
  14 0x02143355 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d5f4)
  15 0x0213a919 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d60c)
  16 0x01ede1e3 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d664)
  17 0x01e706f8 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d690)
  18 0x01e710fa EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d700)
  19 0x01e70510 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d78c)
  20 0x01dd0355 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d7a0)
  21 0x01dd0397 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d7ac)
  22 0x021347f5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d7c0)
  23 0x02134b37 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d7d8)
  24 0x02f0baee EntryPoint+0x4a57c4() in eif launcher (0x0032d800)
  25 0x0252ae76 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032d820)
  26 0x100fae31 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032d864)
  27 0x1010d5b1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032d8c0)
  28 0x1010c41b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032d8ec)
  29 0x1039382f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032d940)
  30 0x103956c6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032da70)
  31 0x06a0623e (0x0032da94)
  32 0x09a4ae31 (0x0032dab8)
  33 0x06a5bc1e (0x0032dad0)
  34 0x06a2f798 (0x0032dafc)
  35 0x10155bdd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032db6c)
  36 0x101553fd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032db9c)
  37 0x10088127 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032dc1c)
  38 0x01e0c78e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032dc70)
  39 0x022c8276 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032dcd4)
  40 0x0235426f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032dcec)
  41 0x021d42e6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032dd08)
  42 0x01efe746 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032dd30)
  43 0x01efe7a7 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ddc4)
  44 0x10450af5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032de10)
  45 0x1036faae EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032de68)
  46 0x103700cc EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032deb0)
  47 0x06a0623e (0x0032ded0)
  48 0x06a5ba85 (0x0032def4)
  49 0x09a4ad15 (0x0032df0c)
  50 0x06a6a714 (0x0032df44)
  51 0x06a5c45b (0x0032df78)
  52 0x06a07315 (0x0032df98)
  53 0x09a4ac1c (0x0032dfb0)
  54 0x06a5bc1e (0x0032dfc8)
  55 0x06a2f798 (0x0032dff4)
  56 0x10155bdd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032e064)
  57 0x101553fd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032e094)
  58 0x10088127 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032e114)
  59 0x01e0c78e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e168)
  60 0x022c8276 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e1cc)
  61 0x0235426f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e1e4)
  62 0x021d42e6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e200)
  63 0x02354407 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e220)
  64 0x01d4da33 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e230)
  65 0x01dfb3b5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e238)
  66 0x101845df EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032e2b0)
  67 0x1018436f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in node (0x0032e2c4)
  68 0x01e0c7f0 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e304)
  69 0x02350a19 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e33c)
  70 0x0235062c EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e390)
  71 0x023504f4 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e3c8)
  72 0x0235047f EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e3ec)
  73 0x01eaa659 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e520)
  74 0x01eaa85d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e550)
  75 0x0227e1cb EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e564)
  76 0x01fac1ce EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e630)
  77 0x01fabe0d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e670)
  78 0x0227e026 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e678)
  79 0x01fabf24 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e6a8)
  80 0x01dac9b1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e6bc)
  81 0x01ea9fe4 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e6c8)
  82 0x01dccd06 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e6dc)
  83 0x0202f4b1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e6f0)
  84 0x0202f6d1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e898)
  85 0x0202f80c EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e8d0)
  86 0x01d4da33 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e8e0)
  87 0x02048d16 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e8f4)
  88 0x01f2f269 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e8fc)
  89 0x01f2ef26 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e90c)
  90 0x01f2f078 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e920)
  91 0x007379ae EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032e988)
  92 0x023c5327 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ebd4)
  93 0x023c49da EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ed44)
  94 0x023c2f8d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ed58)
  95 0x023c2fe5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ed74)
  96 0x023c3001 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ed8c)
  97 0x023c55b0 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032eda0)
  98 0x007379ae EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ee08)
  99 0x006f375d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fa6c)
  100 0x006f25e6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fbdc)
  101 0x0073986d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fc10)
  102 0x006f327e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fcd8)
  103 0x006ef6d5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fcfc)
  104 0x00bfdb02 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fdd4)
  105 0x00930a77 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fde8)
  106 0x009309c7 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fe3c)
  107 0x0077cf8e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fe4c)
  108 0x004f4154 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032fee4)
  109 0x02a66285 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in eif launcher (0x0032ff30)
  110 0x7b454882 in kernel32 (+0x34881) (0x0032ff48)
  111 0x7b454cfc in kernel32 (+0x34cfb) (0x0032ffd8)
  112 0x7b45488e in kernel32 (+0x3488d) (0x0032ffec)
0x01d995ff EntryPoint+0xffffffff in eif launcher: movl  0x24(%edi),%eax
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (52 modules)
PE    400000- 3ac8000   Export          eif launcher
PE   3ad0000- 3e5b000   Deferred        ffmpeg
PE  10000000-10e20000   Export          node
PE  7a840000-7a844000   Deferred        opengl32
PE  7b020000-7b023000   Deferred        kernelbase
PE  7b420000-7b5db000   Export          kernel32
PE  7bc30000-7bc34000   Deferred        ntdll
PE  7d790000-7d79f000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  7da00000-7da04000   Deferred        winex11
PE  7daa0000-7daa3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0
PE  7dac0000-7dac3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
PE  7dad0000-7dad3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
PE  7dae0000-7dae3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
PE  7db00000-7db03000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
PE  7db10000-7db13000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
PE  7dd40000-7dd57000   Deferred        oleacc
PE  7dd90000-7dd94000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  7ddd0000-7ddd3000   Deferred        msimg32
PE  7de10000-7de18000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  7df20000-7df23000   Deferred        fontsub
PE  7df40000-7df43000   Deferred        dwrite
PE  7dfd0000-7dfd3000   Deferred        ncrypt
PE  7dfe0000-7dfe4000   Deferred        dwmapi
PE  7e040000-7e044000   Deferred        wined3d
PE  7e1a0000-7e1a4000   Deferred        dxgi
PE  7e1d0000-7e1db000   Deferred        mpr
PE  7e210000-7e22f000   Deferred        wininet
PE  7e2b0000-7e2bb000   Deferred        winspool
PE  7e300000-7e303000   Deferred        shcore
PE  7e350000-7ec26000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7ed40000-7ee22000   Deferred        comdlg32
PE  7ee80000-7ee84000   Deferred        imm32
PE  7eeb0000-7eeb3000   Deferred        usp10
PE  7ef20000-7ef9e000   Deferred        comctl32
PE  7f0a0000-7f0a8000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  7f110000-7f113000   Deferred        uiautomationcore
PE  7f140000-7f144000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE  7f1c0000-7f1c9000   Deferred        msacm32
PE  7f200000-7f204000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  7f2b0000-7f2d8000   Deferred        ole32
PE  7f400000-7f47d000   Deferred        winmm
PE  7f4c0000-7f4c3000   Deferred        userenv
PE  7f4e0000-7f4e4000   Deferred        iphlpapi
PE  7f520000-7f524000   Deferred        msvcrt
PE  7f5e0000-7f5e4000   Deferred        version
PE  7f620000-7f708000   Deferred        user32
PE  7f840000-7f844000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  7f8d0000-7f8d7000   Deferred        gdi32
PE  7fa20000-7fa24000   Deferred        ws2_32
PE  f79f0000-f79f3000   Deferred        api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-2
PE  f7b10000-f7b13000   Deferred        powrprof
PE  f7d50000-f7d54000   Deferred        psapi
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000024    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 plugplay.exe
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
00000018 winedevice.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001b    0
    00000019    0
0000001f explorer.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000026    0
    00000020    0
00000022 winedevice.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000025    0
    00000023    0
00000043 EiF Launcher.exe
    00000073    0
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    0000005a    0
    00000059    0
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000054    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000051    0
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0
    0000004e    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    0000004b    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
    00000048    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
00000097 EiF Launcher.exe
    000000ce    0
    000000cf    0
    000000cb    0
    000000bd    0
    000000c2    0
    000000c1    0
    000000b8    0
    000000ba    0
    000000bc    0
    000000b9    0
    000000bb    0
    000000b6    0
    000000b1    0
    000000b5    0
    000000b4    0
    000000b2    0
    000000b3    0
    000000ac    0
    000000a7    0
    000000ae    0
    000000ad    0
    000000b0    0
    000000ab    0
    000000a9    0
    000000a0    0
    000000a3    0
    000000af    0
    000000aa    0
    000000a6    0
    000000a4    0
    000000a1    0
    000000a5    0
000000c3 (D) C:\Program Files\EiF Launcher\EiF Launcher.exe
    000000d8    0
    000000d2    0
    000000d0    0
    000000d6    0
    000000cd    0
    000000c5   -2
    000000ca    0
    000000d1    0
    000000c6    0
    000000be    0
    000000c4    0
    000000c9    0
    000000c8    0
    000000c7    0
    000000bf    0
    000000b7    0
    000000c0    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.4.0-54-generic
```

I did some research, and ran into this: https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=31526

Which fits my situation perfectly. I followed it and attempted to install the fonts as recommended. When I did that, the fonts are taking forever to install and are stuck at the terminal output:

```
mike@Ubuntu:~$ WINEPREFIX=~/.wineEiF winetricks allfonts
Executing mkdir -p /home/mike
Using winetricks 20200412 - sha256sum: 7651c93e39fcb080483c38836513bf912273a87ea97d137f6b958ed3d9628c3d with wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1) and WINEARCH=win32
Executing w_do_call allfonts
Executing mkdir -p /home/mike
Executing load_allfonts 
Executing w_do_call andale
Executing mkdir -p /home/mike
Executing load_andale 
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/mike/.wineEiF/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp /home/mike/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/andale32.exe
------------------------------------------------------
Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/mike/.wineEiF terminate
```

Which, lead me to this article: https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/1288
I'm at wine version 5, and Winetricks version 20200412, which this article says being at wine version 4, and a 2019 version of winetricks resolved that issue.

So, I figured I would stop here and ask for help haha!

As I said, I'm also using a fresh prefix, which is 32bit, as the code seems to say that I need 32bit as opposed to 64bit.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do winetricks and from the GUI run the font install. For some reason, it wouldn't do it from the CLI in terminal. Once I did that, I get my launcher up now :)